# Action on Pairs, On Sets and on points in GAP

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, gap

I am trying to understand GAP in group action. I am confused in few things what is the difference between action on pairs, on sets, with the domain sometimes on list, and on blocks. Please help me to clarify these things. Thanks.

Comment: Posted an answer, but can't see what do you mean by "with the domain sometimes on list, and on blocks" - could you please clarify that? Thanks.

Comment: On blocks I mean, sometimes we check primitivity or transitivity. if the action is not transitive then we find blocks of the list. After that we define an action on blocks. For reference you can see on GAP tutorial chapter 5 Groups and Homomorphisms page 42.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Group Actions"](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap41.html) chapter of the GAP reference manual documents standard actions, and if you scroll until `OnTuplesTuples`, there will be a common example covering all of them. I will just take from there examples of the three actions in question, and try to shed more light.

First, create $A_4$ as `g`:

```
gap> g:=Group((1,2,3),(2,3,4));;
gap> AsList(g);
[ (), (2,3,4), (2,4,3), (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,2), (1,3,4), 
  (1,3)(2,4), (1,4,2), (1,4,3), (1,4)(2,3) ]
```

The group `g` acts transitively on the set $1,2,3,4$ so $1$ may be mapped to any of the points $1,2,3,4$:

```
gap> Orbit(g,1,OnPoints);
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

For example:

```
gap> 1^(1,2)(3,4);
2
gap> 1^(1,3,2);
3
gap> 1^(1,4,2);
4
```

`OnPairs` extends `OnPoints` on pairs of points. A permutation `s` from `g` will map the pair `[i,j]` to `[i^s,j^s]`:

```
gap> Orbit(g,[1,2],OnPairs);
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1 ], 
  [ 1, 4 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 4, 3 ] ]
```

For example,

```
gap> OnPairs([1,2],(1,2,3));
[ 2, 3 ]
gap> OnPairs([1,2],(1,3,4));
[ 3, 2 ]
```

etc.

Finally, `OnSets` acts as `OnPairs` but additionally sorts the entries of the result:

```
gap> Orbit(g,[1,2],OnSets);
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]
```

Thus, `[ 2, 3 ]` and `[ 3, 2 ]` are not distinguished in the case of `OnSets` action:

```
gap> OnSets([1,2],(1,2,3));
[ 2, 3 ]
gap> OnSets([1,2],(1,3,4));
[ 2, 3 ]
```

Hope this helps to clarify things.

Comment: Nicely done. ${}{}$